# Reading JS variable

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have the following json file with several information needed in my JS application.

Example:

```
var stuff = {"id":"stuff_1","text":"Insert text here","correct":"true","x":"283","y":"180"};
var points= ['123','1566','125667','433456'];
```

Need to read the file with PHP and only return one of the variables as request.

PHP's function 'json_decode()' doesn't work since it isn't JSON. I cannot modify the file described above. The client demands to be as is.

How can it be done?

Thanks in advance

Comment: This isn't valid JSON.

Comment: You haven't posted any PHP showing [what you've tried](http://whathaveyoutried.com). Without starter code there's no good way to answer the question other than "you're doing it wrong".

Comment: Is your file static..ie will it change?  If not, you can just link to it with a script tag.

Answer (score 2):

It's not valid JSON. Use this JavaScript code and `json_decode` in PHP will work:

```
{ 
  "cenas": {"id":"cenas","text":"Insert text here","correct":"true","x":"283","y":"180"},
  "points": ["123","1566","125667","433456"]
}
```

(Also notice the double quotes instead of single)

Answer (score 1):

The file you have is simply javascript.  If the content is static, you can link it directly

```
<script src="scripts/mysnippet.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
  alert('yay, i can see: ' + cenas.id);
</script>
```

Or if it is dynamic, you can use javascript to link it at runtime.

```
<script>
  // inject js
  var snippet = document.createElement("script");
  snippet.type = "text/javascript";
  snippet.src="http://url-to-snippet/mysnippet.js";
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(snippet);

  window.onload = function(){
    alert('yay i can use ' + cenas.id);
  };
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks Itiong_sh, that became very useful. Thanks :)